# Embed stock ticker that can be dynamically changed with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, embed, stock

I'm looking for something like this http://finance.yahoo.com/badges to embed on my page.  The problem is I want to be able to change the ticker symbol by passing it with some Javascript.  Is there anything like this?

Initially, I tried just putting Google Finance in an iframe but they set X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN so I can't.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: You're asking to circumvent a built-in security feature. Why would anyone help?

Comment: I'm not trying to circumvent it.  I just want to be able to embed stock information on my page...

Comment: Use a server-side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same thing, eventually I found something almost perfect [Simple PHP Stock Ticker and Javascript Marquee for valid XHTML](http://techblog.shanock.com/articles/9/simple-php-stock-ticker-and-javascript-marquee-for-valid-xhtml)
You will have to tweak it a little bit in order to make the php work depends on your hosting
(I had a problem that twas sold with the right .htaccess file on the host)
and if your using a any type of cms you'll have to create the "stockcache" directory in the root not any other category, anw it works perfectly and you can choose whatever symbols you like